# What is the use of integrating svn with the apache?

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn

Can anyone help me clear this up:

- What is the advantage of integrating SVN with the Apache?
- Without integrating SVN with Apache, does this mean that we will not able to use SVN as a centralized VCS?
- Is it possible to install SVN without using Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal is to be able to access your SVN repositories using HTTP.

It is also posible to run an svnserve daemon, which will make your repositories available through the `svn:` protocol, bur HTTP is the standard and don't cause problems with firewalls.

What's sure is that you need at least a server to make the repo available remotely.

Read http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig